# No tests were found / collected 0 items / empty suite

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pytest

Currently learning Python to automate API and faced the first significant issue I found no solution for.

When I try to run my test either with Run or with terminal by `python -m pytest` or just `pytest/py.test` commands, I get this in the Run tab:

```
/Users/usr/PycharmProjects/project/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py --path /Users/usr/PycharmProjects/project/tests/test_google_maps_api.py  
Testing started at 20:20 ... 
Launching pytest with arguments /Users/usr/PycharmProjects/project/tests/test_google_maps_api.py --no-header --no-summary -q in /Users/usr/PycharmProjects/project/tests

test session starts ============================== 
collecting ... collected 0 items

no tests ran in 0.24s =============================

Process finished with exit code 5

Empty suite
```

Or this in the terminal:

```
test session starts =========================================================================================== 
platform darwin -- Python 3.11.1, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.0.0 rootdir: /Users/usr/PycharmProjects/project 
collected 0 items                                                                                                                                                                                        

no tests ran in 0.13s ==========================================================================================
```

Here is the structure of my project:

[image: Project structure]

And here is the code:

test_http_methods_here.py file:

```
import requests

class test_http_methods:
   
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
cookies = ""

    @staticmethod
    def test_get(url):
        result = requests.get(url, headers=test_http_methods.headers, cookies=test_http_methods.cookies)
        return result

    @staticmethod
    def test_post(url, body): 
        result = requests.post(url, json=body, headers=test_http_methods.headers, cookies=test_http_methods.cookies)
        return result

    @staticmethod
    def test_put(url, body):
        result = requests.put(url, json=body, headers=test_http_methods.headers, cookies=test_http_methods.cookies)
        return result

    @staticmethod
    def test_delete(url, body):
        result = requests.delete(url, json=body, headers=test_http_methods.headers, cookies=test_http_methods.cookies)
        return result
```

test_api.py file:

```
from workfiles.test_http_methods_here import test_http_methods

base_url = "https://rahulshettyacademy.com"
key = 'key=qaclick123'

class test_google_maps_api():

    @staticmethod
    def test_create_new_place(): 

        json_for_new_place = {
            "location": {
                "lat": -38.383494,
                "lng": 33.427362
            }, "accuracy": 50,
                "name": "Frontline house",
                "phone_number": "(+91) 983 893 3937",
                "address": "29, side layout, cohen 09",
                "types": [
                 "shoe park",
                "shop"
            ],
                 "website": "http://google.com",
                "language": "French-IN"
        }

        post_resource = '/maps/api/place/add/json'
        post_url = base_url + post_resource + key
        print (post_url)
        result_post = test_http_methods.test_post(post_url, json_for_new_place) 
        print(result_post.text)
        return result_post
```

test_google_maps_api.py file:

```
import requests
from requests import Response

from workfiles.test_api import test_google_maps_api

class test_create_new_place():

    def test_create_new_place(self):
        print("Method POST")
        result_post: requests.Response = test_google_maps_api.test_create_new_place()
```

I have already tried the following:

1. Adding and removing `__init__.py` file in every directory
2. Adding and removing `conftest.py` file in every directory
3. Adding `test/tests` to the `workfiles` folder name
4. Naming every method/function with `test_...`
5. Setting up pytest as Default test runner
6. Adding my `autom_api_project` directory as Content Root in Project Structure
7. Clearing cache and restarting PyCharm after all these
8. Adding empty `tests.py` file to the root directory
9. Something else I can't remember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test classes are not adhering to Pytest's [naming conventions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery) and therefore the discovery fails. Test classes must be named using `Test` prefix, that is with uppercase `T`.